# Pythonにおいて「宣言」と「定義」は区別されますか？

Tags: python

vscodeを使っていて、

go to definition

go to declaration

が変わらないようにみえますが、

インタプリタ言語であるPythonではあまり重要ではない違い、もしくは、区別されませんか？

Comment: 厳密には「Pythonにおいて」と「VSCodeのPython拡張機能において」のどちらか、あるいは両方を聞きたいということでしょうか？ その辺を明確にしておいた方が助言や回答が付きやすそうです。

Comment: どちらでも結構です

Comment: [Editing Python Code in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing)

Answer (score 1):

他の言語では、"宣言" の定義は、変数のデータ型と共に変数の存在を示すために使用されます。Pythonでは、変数をそれぞれの値で初期化するだけです。

**Python**

```py
#初期化
number = 10
data = ["hello", 1, "naokiri", 16, (1,2)]
```

**Java**

```java
//宣言
int number;
number = 10; //使う
//宣言と使用
string letter = "naokiri";
```